# is !5 supposed to make mac's terminal say things?

Tags: macos, unix

I know that the command 
say "something" in mac's terminal would make it say stuff.
I am new to Unix and since OS X is UNIX based, I was trying to teach myself the commands and I read that !5 would recall the last five commands in the terminal's history. 
when I typed that, the terminal started saying stuff!
is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Search the bash manpage for "HISTORY EXPANSION"...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't press Command+F5?

Comment: Type `history` and see what the 5th command was. !# would run whatever # you entered (not the last five, just the fifth). So it should call whatever number. Did you run `say ...` as that number?

Answer (score 1):

If you press !5 (bang-5) at the command line, if you are in a CSH varient....you'll cause the 5th command since the particular shell invokation was started entered to be recalled and executed as if you entered it on the command line.

Depending on what the 5th command in your particular case was, you'd be seeing the output from that command.

Comment: Ditto for bash(1), and I believe other shells too.